# Estoy haciendo un procedure que lee un cursor que me dá el error "PLS-00402: alias required"

Tags: sql

> PLS-00402: alias required in SELECT list of cursor to avoid duplicate column names

```
PROCEDURE CARGA_BOLETAS_FORMIN (PERIODO IN DATE, FECHA_INICIO IN DATE , FECHA_TERMINO IN DATE)
IS
      CURSOR RESCATA_BOLETAS IS 
               SELECT S.NUMERO_BOLETA SNUMBOL,
           S.RUT_CLIENTE       SRUTCLI,
           S.RUT_DV_CLIENTE    SRUTCLI_DV, 
           S.NOMBRE_CLIENTE    SNOMCLI,
           S.FECHA_BOLETA      SFECBOL, 
           S.ESTADO            SBOLESTADO,
           S.AUD_PRM_FECHA     SPRMFEC,  
           S.NUMERO_BOLETA_ORIGINAL SNUMBOLORI, 
           S.TIPO_DOCUMENTO     STIPDOC,
           S.TIPO_NOTACREDITO   SNC,
           S.NUMERO_BOLETA_RELACIONADA    SNUMBOL, 
           S.FECHA_BOLETA_RELACIONADA     SFECBOLREL,
           SUM(B.TOTAL) STOTAL ,
           SUM(B.TOTAL_CON_IVA)   STOTALCIVA,
           SUM(B.DESCUENTO)  SDESCUEN,
           SUM(B.RECARGO)    SRECARGO,
           SUM(B.VALOR_IVA) SVALOR_IVA
      FROM VIV.SGV_BOLETAVENTA S, VIV.SGV_BOLETAVENTADETALLE B 
           WHERE S.NUMERO_BOLETA = B.NUMERO_BOLETA 
           GROUP BY 
           S.NUMERO_BOLETA ,
           S.RUT_CLIENTE   ,
           S.RUT_DV_CLIENTE  , 
           S.NOMBRE_CLIENTE ,
           S.FECHA_BOLETA   , 
           S.ESTADO         ,
           S.AUD_PRM_FECHA  ,  
           S.NUMERO_BOLETA_ORIGINAL, 
           S.TIPO_DOCUMENTO  ,
           S.TIPO_NOTACREDITO  ,
           S.NUMERO_BOLETA_RELACIONADA , 
           S.FECHA_BOLETA_RELACIONADA;


BEGIN

       for reg in rescata_boletas loop
            INSERT INTO CNT_GD.DOCUMENTOS (
                     COD_SOCIEDAD, TIPO_DOCTO, FOLIO_DOCTO, 
                     TIPO_TRANSACCION, FECHA_EMISION, HORA_EMISION, 
                     RUT_CLIENTE, RUT_CLIENTE_DV, RZN_SOCIAL_CLIENTE, 
                     DIREC_CLIENTE_CALLE, DIREC_CLIENTE_COMUNA, DIREC_CLIENTE_CIUDAD, 
                     CODIGO_DESTINO, DESCRIPCION_DESTINO, DIREC_DESPACHO_CALLE, 
                     DIREC_DESPACHO_CIUDAD, GIRO_CLIENTE, ESTADO, 
                     VALOR_NETO, TIPO_DOCTO_REL, NUM_DOCTO_REL, 
                     ACUSE_FECHA_RECEP, ACUSE_COPIA_CEDIBLE, ACUSE_OBSERVACION, 
                     ACUSE_FECHA, ACUSE_USUARIO, FECHA_ACT, 
                     USUA_ACT) 
              VALUES ( 103,'BE' ,SNUMBOL ,
                     1 ,SFECBOL ,  SFECBOL ,                           -- Las boletas siempre son de transacción venta
                     SRUTCLI, SRUTCLI_DV, SNOMCLI ,
                       '0' ,'0' ,'0' ,
                       '0','0' ,'0' ,
                       '0','0' ,'0' ,
                    STOTAL,'0' ,0 ,
                    to_date('00:00:00 HHMISS'),0,0 ,
                    to_date('20180101','yyyymmdd'),0 ,SYSDATE ,USER);     
        END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu error esta en al momento de hacer el `select` dentro del `cursor`. Tienes dos columnas con el mismo nombre en el alias *SNUMBOL*:

```
CURSOR RESCATA_BOLETAS IS 
    //Primera variable SNUMBOL
    SELECT S.NUMERO_BOLETA SNUMBOL,
           S.RUT_CLIENTE       SRUTCLI,
           S.RUT_DV_CLIENTE    SRUTCLI_DV, 
           S.NOMBRE_CLIENTE    SNOMCLI,
           S.FECHA_BOLETA      SFECBOL, 
           S.ESTADO            SBOLESTADO,
           S.AUD_PRM_FECHA     SPRMFEC,  
           S.NUMERO_BOLETA_ORIGINAL SNUMBOLORI, 
           S.TIPO_DOCUMENTO     STIPDOC,
           S.TIPO_NOTACREDITO   SNC,
           //Segunda variable SNUMBOL
           S.NUMERO_BOLETA_RELACIONADA    SNUMBOL, 
           S.FECHA_BOLETA_RELACIONADA     SFECBOLREL,
           SUM(B.TOTAL) STOTAL ,
           SUM(B.TOTAL_CON_IVA)   STOTALCIVA,
           SUM(B.DESCUENTO)  SDESCUEN,
           SUM(B.RECARGO)    SRECARGO,
           SUM(B.VALOR_IVA) SVALOR_IVA
```

Por lo cual deberias de usuar otro alias, de la siguiente manera:

```
CURSOR RESCATA_BOLETAS IS 
    SELECT S.NUMERO_BOLETA SNUMBOL,
           S.RUT_CLIENTE       SRUTCLI,
           S.RUT_DV_CLIENTE    SRUTCLI_DV, 
           S.NOMBRE_CLIENTE    SNOMCLI,
           S.FECHA_BOLETA      SFECBOL, 
           S.ESTADO            SBOLESTADO,
           S.AUD_PRM_FECHA     SPRMFEC,  
           S.NUMERO_BOLETA_ORIGINAL SNUMBOLORI, 
           S.TIPO_DOCUMENTO     STIPDOC,
           S.TIPO_NOTACREDITO   SNC,
           S.NUMERO_BOLETA_RELACIONADA    SNUMBOLREL, 
           S.FECHA_BOLETA_RELACIONADA     SFECBOLREL,
           SUM(B.TOTAL) STOTAL ,
           SUM(B.TOTAL_CON_IVA)   STOTALCIVA,
           SUM(B.DESCUENTO)  SDESCUEN,
           SUM(B.RECARGO)    SRECARGO,
           SUM(B.VALOR_IVA) SVALOR_IVA
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Efectivamente traté de buscar la columna repetida y no la encontraba.... Gracias nuevamente